# Autocomplete service of hereapi is not working

Tags: autocomplete, postman, geocoding, here-api, geocode

In the last few days, I created an account on here in order to test the gecording feature,
but today I don't receive any result, I am testing the endpoint using postman!

Does anyone currently face the same problem?

Comment: What is the returned HTTP status code? What are the request url and request parameters you tried?

Comment: are you getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `https` instead of `http` in your request as below:

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=<b>&apiKey=apikey
```